# starting off with non trivial programs -- publish or not?

Tags: programming-languages, project-management, personal-projects

I've just started making some simple but non trivial(i think) programs in Ubuntu -- as of now have made a small xkcd scraper, which i plan to develop into a multi webcomic downloader+viewer

At this point, would it be a good idea to start publishing the code on a site like Github or launchpad? (currently I'm not really worried about people copying my code/licensing)

Or is it better to publish the code only after the program is completed?

Also, can you suggest some such sites where I can post such codes and get suggestions for improvements/discuss the code with others?

Comment: Scraping content off websites may be a violation of their usage terms. Check with each website before you publishing far and wide. Look for "Terms and Conditions" and/or "Acceptable Use Policy" at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Should I look for them allowing it specifically, or denying it specifically?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a good idea to push it to a public repository for multiple reasons -

- Motivates you to keep it up, maintain it
- You might get unexpected feedback from others
- Looks good on your resume/profile/blog

So even if it's not complete yet, put it up somewhere. Don't be worried about incompleteness, because people who visit will know it's a work in progress.

Update : As Skilldrick mentions, [www.github.com](http://www.github.com) is a great repos.

Comment: could you suggest an appropriate public repository ?

Comment: @Akash Start using github and just put everything there.